# Hiding loading animation running in one thread after task completed in another

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a button that when pressed a separate thread is started to display a loading animation. The reason for doing this is so that the loading gif is displayed as soon as the button is pressed, the other procedure continues and when complete the alert shows. The problem I have is hiding the animation after the alert is closed.

```
- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender { 
    [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(loadAnimation) toTarget:self withObject:nil];

    ... do other things;

    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle: @"Complete" message:@"other things done" delegate: self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
    [alert setTag:1];
    [alert show];
}

-(void) alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    if (alertView.tag == 1) {
        loadingGif.hidden=YES;
    }
}
```

The loading gif:

```
- (void) loadAnimation {
loadingGif.hidden=NO;
NSArray *imageArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:[UIImage imageNamed:@"0.gif"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"1.gif"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"2.gif"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"3.gif"],  nil];

loadingGif = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(487, 520, 50, 50)];
[self.view addSubview:loadingGif];
loadingGif.animationImages = imageArray;
loadingGif.animationDuration = 1.5;
[loadingGif startAnimating];
}
```

The animation loads fine but it does not stop once the OK from the alert has been clicked. Is it possible to hide the animation from the main thread once it has been started in another?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that you should be making UI changes on a thread other than the main thread. An alternative approach would be to show the animation immediately and use NSTimer to schedule the other stuff to be executed shortly thereafter:

```
- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender { 

    // load animation on the main thread
    [self loadAnimation];

    // start a timer to do other stuff in 1 ms (will get executed on main thread)
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.001
       target:self
       selector:@selector(doOtherStuff)
       userInfo:nil
       repeats:NO]; 
}

- (void)doOtherStuff { 

    ... do other things;

    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle: @"Complete" message:@"other things done" delegate: self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
    [alert setTag:1];
    [alert show];
```

Answer (score 1):

I think 'loadAnimation' or 'UIAlertView' is running in background so setHidden is not work as you want.

Why don't you change your code like this to make sure 'wait until your work is done' and 'running in main thread'

--

-- changed

I'm sorry that I used unnecessary background block.
please check again.

```
 - (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender
{
    [self loadAnimation];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^{
    //        ... do other things

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle: @"Complete" message:@"other things done" delegate: self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
            [alert setTag:1];
            [alert show];
        });
    });
}

-(void) alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if (alertView.tag == 1)
    {
        loadingGif.hidden=YES;
    }
}
```

Comment: I appreciate the answer. That would explain it as similar (without the alert) does hide the loading gif. I will give it a go.Thanks

Comment: @RGriffiths I changed my code to remove unnecessary blocks. Sorry about it.